# MyPy gives an "incompatible type "auto"; expected "str" " error when using auto() with Enums inheriting from str

Tags: python, enums, mypy

It is common practice with Python Enums to inherit from `str` and then override `_generate_next_value` to return the enum name so that the `auto()` function can be used to simply return the name as a string. However this raises an error in MyPy.

For example if you declare:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class StrEnum(str, Enum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        return name

class Foo(StrEnum):
    bar = auto()
    baz = auto()

def takes_a_string(s: str):
   pass

takes_a_string(s=Foo.bar)
```

MyPy will give an error

```
Argument "s" to "takes_a_string" has incompatible type "auto"; expected "str"
```

Additionally trying to add type hints to `_generate_next_value` will results in errors like:

```
Signature of "generate_next_value" incompatible with supertype "Enum"
Self argument missing for a non-static method (or an invalid type for self)
```

How to resolve this without using `# type: ignore` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subclass `enum.auto` like:

```
from enum import auto

class autostr(auto):
    value: str = _auto_null
```

then

```
class Foo(StrEnum):
    bar = autostr()
    baz = autostr()

def takes_a_string(s: str):
   pass

takes_a_string(s=Foo.bar)
```

will pass the MyPy type checking without an error.

Additionally you can change `StrEnum._generate_next_value_` to be a `staticmethod`:

```
class StrEnum(str, Enum):
    @staticmethod
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start: int, count: int, last_values: List[Any]) -> str:
        return name
```

to avoid MyPy complaining about the supertype incompatibility

as suggested by Guido himself here: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7591